# php mysql getTable function impossible?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi so i want to know if there is a way of making a global getTable function for example:

```
function getTable($sql_query)
{
    $conn=connectDB();
    $result = $conn->query($sql_query);     
    if(!$result)
    {
        $conn->close();
        die("MySQL error ");
    }
    $conn->close();
    return $result;
}
```

I tried this but i couldn't find a way to read it later, like each row. 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you get the result which is a resource, then you close that resource and return it from the function which is probably always null or a resource with nothing in it? Give this a try:

```
function getTable($sql_query)
{
    $conn=connectDB();
    $query_result = $conn->query($sql_query);     
    if(!$query_result)
    {
        $conn->close();
        die("MySQL error ");
    }
    $result = array();
    while($result[] = $query_result->fetch_assoc());
    $conn->close();
    return $result;
}
```

**Note:** the performance on this will be really bad roughly O(2n^2) when you go to loop through everything again when this is returned, maybe making a class would be better and have it handle the connection better.

Comment: and how would you read each line when it is returned? each row and column

Comment: `foreach($returned as $row){echo $row['columnFromDatabase'].'<br/>';}`

Comment: when i echo one of the $row['colName'] it says "array" wft?

Comment: do `var_dump($row);` instead of echo, what does that look like?

Comment: IT DOES. lol it shows:array(4) {...} and all the columns and their value inside.

Comment: are you doing something like `$row = getTable($query); echo $row['colName'];` ?

Comment: nono im doing the way you are supposed to. all in the same function (conect, run query get result) but when i do $row["colName"] it says "ArrayArray". Whats up with that? i checked the db and thats not the value yet when i do the var_dump($row) it shows all the columns and values right.. and yes its the same column name. :/

Comment: When trying to echo an array, it will output the word Array. Maybe the fetch assoc isnt working the same on your side..? Using the var dump you did, you should be able to access a value using the tree it shows, you just need to do for and foreach loops to make that more dynamic.

Comment: when i var_dump($row.["colName"]) it says: string(10)"ArrayArray"